# Reading and Overwriting radio button values in mysql database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm describing the correcting functioning of the process. 
First the user posts an order, and the `status` initially is set to NOT APPROVED, but his manager is able to see the order request and can change the `status` to APPROVED, and then it is forwarded to the IT guy and he can change `status` to UNDER PROCUREMENT. 
I am using radio buttons for `gm` and `IT guy` for changing the status. However, i am unable to change the status. Here's the code for better understanding

```
echo'<th>Product</th><th>Type</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Order Status</th>';

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$type=$row["type"];
$make=$row["make"];
$quantity=$row["quantity"];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['make'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['quantity'] . "</td>";
    echo '<form method="post">';
//Radio buttons used here
    echo '<td><input type="radio" name="status[' . $row['order_id'] . ']" value="not approved" checked >Not Approved<br>
          <input type="radio" name="status[' . $row['order_id'] . ']" value="approved">Approved</td>';
    echo '</form>';

    $_SESSION['radio'] = $_POST['status[]'];
    $qr = "UPDATE order_info SET status = '".$_SESSION['radio']."' WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";
    $rs = mysqli_query($con3,$qr) or die(mysqli_error($con3));
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

Also, I want the radio button to be checked by default according to the status of the order.

Comment: *sidenote:*  `border="0px"` is deprecated & incorrect; use CSS instead; and what is `<cb>` tag?

Comment: Sorry, edited my code.. `<cb>` tag was useless.

Comment: Any help for fixing the error would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your input names:

```
echo '<td><cb><input type="radio" name="status[' . $row['order_id'] . ']" value="not approved" checked >Not Approved<br>
          <input type="radio" name="status[' . $row['order_id'] . ']" value="approved">Approved</cb></td>';
    echo '</form>';
```

You're creating an array. You can see this with this example:

```
<form method ='post'>
<input type='radio' name='status["25"]' value='not approved'>Not Approved
<input type='radio' name='status[25]' value='approved'>Approved
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>
</form>

<pre>
<?
session_start();
print_r($_POST);
$_SESSION['radio'] = $_POST['status'];
print_r($_SESSION);
?>
</pre>
```

This may have been to keep the order_id, but your update query is not specifying an order_id and will update all rows for that username. If you're only updating one row at a time, you can pass the order id with a hidden field (if you even need it?):

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="'.$row['order_id'].'">';
```

Which means you're probably missing an "and order_id =" qualifier in your update.

Comment: I am using an array so that I am able to select 1 radio button FROM EVERY ROW, without that I was able to select only a single radio button FOR ALL THE ROWS.

Comment: So you intend to update multiple database rows at once, where the unique id is order_id? That update isn't going to work. You can use the status array, but you'll need to loop through them to get key -> value, update where order_id =, and it's $_SESSION['radio'] = $_POST['status']; not $_SESSION['radio'] = $_POST['status[]'];

Comment: Can you please explain it with the proper syntax? I'm unable to understand without it.

Comment: **incorrect**. The 2nd piece of code listing will lead to PHP's *header already sent* error.

Comment: @Raptor, What do you suggest then?